# Desktop programs to beautify code

Tags: windows-7, desktop-client, code-beautification

Sometimes I have a piece of code, which could be SQL or JSON or JavaScript or anything else, and I want to beautify it, i.e. make it nicely indented and colorized so it'll be easy to read.

If you search online you can find a beautifier for any language, for example this for SQL: http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

The problem is, I don't want to be sharing my code online. If there was a single desktop program (for Windows 7) that I can use which will beautify code, and code of any kind of language (at least the popular ones), that would be ideal.

Comment: For which operating system? Do you want to export the beautified code (if so, in which format) or is it only about displaying?

Comment: If you google for it and skip the first five to ten  results, you will also find offline formatters for any language, like this one: http://architectshack.com/PoorMansTSqlFormatter.ashx, this one http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/, or this one http://astyle.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Operating system: Windows 7. No need to export the code.

Comment: Thanks @DocBrown but I prefer desktop software.

Comment: For python I use [JetBrain](https://www.jetbrains.com/)'s [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) which restructures your code to the [python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). JetBrains has several editors, they might do what you are looking for in [Java](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), SQL etc.

Comment: It's 5 years old, but see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731357/multi-language-command-line-source-code-formatter

Comment: @DocBrown Sorry, I missed the fact that you pointed out desktop software. I checked these 3 out and they don't support enough languages.

Comment: @RamRachum: my comment was not intended to give you a real answer, it was just intended to demonstrate that working on your "google foo" might help.

Comment: If I understand clearly: your are looking for notepad++ with automatic indentation capabilities?

Comment: @MyNameIsNotToBeDisplayedHere Pretty much yeah, but I don't want to install a full-blown text editor for that. I just need automatic indentation, that's it, I edit my files in other editors.

Comment: Your text editor doesn't offer syntax highlighting or code formatting?

Comment: @Huey None of the editors I use offer automatic code formatting for dozens of different languages like I asked in my question.

Comment: OP might be satisfied with astyle, if he doesn't care that it might break his code.

Comment: use code::blocks

Answer (score 4):

[Atom.io](https://atom.io/) is another text tool with beautification functionality tools [available](https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify). The package I linked will format about a dozen languages out of the box. Others can be added through separate configuration files (if atom-beautify doesn't know how to beautify the language you're working in, it will tell you were you can find download the needed configuration files). There are linters and debugging tools available for Atom well.

Answer (score 2):

Notepad++ has color highlight for many languages built in and reformatting plugins for some languages, e.g. Javascript

https://notepad-plus-plus.org/